# The numbers are joined instead of adding up

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have little problem with 'reduce' function.

```
let array = [
  0: "720"
  1: "1080"
]
array.reduce((a,b) => a + b)
```

There is problem, this return me `7201080`, but i need `1800`

Comment: Hint: there are no numbers in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need convert string in number `array.reduce((a,b) => +a + +b)`

Comment: @B4UTR3N It is good to set initialValue in reduce, `array.reduce((a,b) => +a + +b, 0)`. In this case you don't need convert a into number, because it always will be number `array.reduce((a,b) => a + +b, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Provide  initial value `0` for reduce callback function and convert string to number using `Number()`

```js
let array = [
   "720",
   "1080"
]
console.log(array.reduce((a,b) => a + Number(b),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You say that your problem is (**bold** emphasis mine):

> The **numbers** are joined instead of adding up

But that is not actually true, and it is not actually your problem.

The *real* problem is that *there are no [number](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#number-value)s in your code*. There are only [string](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-string-value)s, and the binary infix `+` operator for strings is [defined to perform string-concatenation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-addition-operator-plus): `"A" + "b" === "Ab" // not 21`.

The "best" way to fix your problem would be to fix it at the *source*, so that you have numbers instead of strings in the first place:

```js
const array = [
  720,
  1080
];

console.log(array.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
// 1800
```

If that is not possible, e.g. because the code that generates this value is third-party code outside of your control, you should sanitize and adapt the data *as soon as it enters your system*, e.g. using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.map) and [`parseInt`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix) like this:

```js
const thirdPartyArray = [
  "720",
  "1080"
];

const myArray = thirdPartyArray.map(str => parseInt(str, 10));

console.log(myArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
// 1800
```